# How to Call a number through a android phone by a command from a web server?

Tags: android

How to send a command from a website as in PAW server app so that the phone calls that number through its service..So its like web server commands phone the number to call, and phone recieves this command via internet and calls the number through the phones network service.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to attempt such a feat, you'd need a few pieces.

1. A program that had permissions to call that was running in the background.
2. This program would need to poll the server periodically, to see if a new number was available.
3. The program would make the call, if a new number was available.

I'm not going to get into any specifics, but this should at least give you a framework from which to go on.